# Why Kotlin code unreachable in my project?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have simple model and I want to use user profil image  and name, but it is throw an error like "Unreachable code" for

> participants.find { it.id != userId }!!.profilePicture

and

> participants.find { it.id != userId }!!.username

```
class Talk(
    val participantsId: ArrayList<String>

): BaseModel(), Serializable {
    var participants = ArrayList<Data>()
    val messages = ArrayList<Message>()

    fun getProfilePicture(userId: String) {
        return
            participants.find { it.id != userId }!!.profilePicture

    }

    fun getTalkName(userId: String) {
        return
            participants.find { it.id != userId }!!.username

    }
}
```

any idea?

Comment: The code must be on the same line as 'return'. An return statement alone on a line just returns.

Comment: Also, you haven't provided return type for these functions.

Comment: @ArpitShukla, I remove return, it work but not show data on list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in Kotlin lines don't need to end with a semicolon (`;`), return followed by a new line is interpreted as a return with no return value (equivalent to `return;` in Java).

You just need to remove the new lines after the `return`s and change the return type of your functions with the actual types you are returning. e.g.: (I've assumed `String` a return type)

```
fun getTalkName(userId: String): String {
    return participants.find { it.id != userId }!!.username
}
```

Comment: I see my mistake now, thnx